# Graded readers for German?

Tags: electronic-resources, german, physical-resources, graded-readers

As several other questions already mentioned, graded readers are a good resources for [extensive reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensive_reading), at least for people who are not yet sufficiently proficient to read texts written for native speakers of the target language.

Where can people find graded readers for German?

Answer (score 6):

There are [**Eli Graded Readers**](https://www.languages-direct.com/books/easy-readers/eli-graded-readers) for several languages, including [German](https://www.languages-direct.com/books/easy-readers/eli-graded-readers?language=3). The books come with a CD containing narrated excerpts from the book. They also contain other content, such as a glossary at the bottom of each page, pre-reading and post-reading activities, and dossiers on culture and the author.

- For level A1, there is, for example [Die Zauberflöte (Emanual Schikaneder)](https://www.languages-direct.com/books/easy-readers/eli-graded-readers/die-zauberflote-emanuel-schikaneder.html), [Kaspar Hauser (Anselm von Feuerbach)](https://www.languages-direct.com/books/easy-readers/eli-graded-readers/kaspar-hauser-anselm-von-feuerbach.html).
- For level A2, there is, for example [Das Nibelungenlied](https://www.languages-direct.com/books/easy-readers/eli-graded-readers/nibelungenlied-anonym.html), [Effi Briest (Theodor Fontane)](https://www.languages-direct.com/books/easy-readers/eli-graded-readers/eli-graded-readers-effi-briest-theodor-fontane.html), [Wilhelm Tell (Schiller)](https://www.languages-direct.com/books/easy-readers/eli-graded-readers/wilhelm-tell-friedrich-schiller-eli-graded-reader.html).
- For level B1, there is, for example [Kleider machen Leute (Gottfried Keller)](https://www.languages-direct.com/books/easy-readers/eli-graded-readers/kleider-machen-leute-gottfried-keller.html), [Die Leiden des jungen Werthers (Goethe)](https://www.languages-direct.com/eli-graded-readers-die-leiden-des-jungen-werthers-johann-wolfgang-von-goethe.html), [Der Sandmann (E.T.A Hoffmann)](https://www.languages-direct.com/eli-graded-readers-der-sandmann-e-t-a-hoffmann.html), [Die Verwandlung (Kafka)](https://www.languages-direct.com/die-verwandlung-franz-kafka-eli-graded-reader.html), [Woyzeck (Büchner)](https://www.languages-direct.com/books/easy-readers/eli-graded-readers/woyzeck-georg-buchner-eli-graded-reader.html).

The German publisher **Klett** has a [series of graded readers](https://www.klett-sprachen.de/lektueren/deutsch-als-fremdsprache/a1/c-485) for levels A1 and A2. The books come with a CD with a narrated version of the entire text, exercises for each chapter and other materials. Some example titles for level A1: [Die Legende des Piraten Störtebeker](https://www.klett-sprachen.de/die-legende-des-piraten-stoertebeker/t-485/9783125560734), [Heidi](https://www.klett-sprachen.de/heidi/t-485/9783126757584), [Das Lasagne-Disaster](https://www.klett-sprachen.de/das-lasagne-desaster/t-485/9783126749152).

Examples for level A2: [Oktoberfest kriminell](https://www.klett-sprachen.de/oktoberfest-kriminell/t-34/9783126751070) (level A1–A2), [Die richtige Taste: Johann Sebastian Bach](https://www.klett-sprachen.de/die-richtige-taste-johann-sebastian-bach/t-486/9783125560741), [Berliner Fußballfieber](https://www.klett-sprachen.de/berliner-fussballfieber/t-486/9783126751131) (A2–B1).

The German publisher **Cornelsen** also has several collections of graded readers: [Junge DaF-Bibliothek](https://www.cornelsen.de/lehrkraefte/reihe/r-7882/ra/titel/back_link/search) (levels A1–A2), [DaF-Bibliothek A1 – A2](https://www.cornelsen.de/erw/reihe/r-7724/ra/titel), [DaF-Bibliothek A2 – B1](https://www.cornelsen.de/erw/1.c.1853637.de) and the Lextra-Lektüren (level A1/A2 or A2/B1).