# Graded readers for English?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, english, graded-readers

Graded readers are a good resources for [extensive reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensive_reading), at least for people who are not yet sufficiently proficient to read texts written for native speakers of the target language.

We have [graded readers for many languages](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graded-readers),  like for [German](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/graded-readers-for-german).

What are good (preferably free) online graded reader resources for English?

As suggested in comments, I looked on ELL, and I found only two suggestions, both closed questions:

- [Tips for easy-to-read unabridged English fiction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97124/tips-for-easy-to-read-unabridged-english-fiction-for-language-learners) - promoting Wizard of Oz, local public libraries (unlikely, if  English is L2) and project Guttenberg
- [Improving reading skills](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63650/improving-reading-skills) - recommending "Start with books for a younger audience" - which are native young speakers, not L2 learners.

So obviously people on ELL know their English, but do not know how to learn it better. We do. :-)

Comment: Good question. I imagine this would be very helpful on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) as well.

Comment: @fi12 Sure, but we don't want to migrate questions away to other sites if they are useful and on topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally look for physical books or e-books when I look for graded readers, but there are a number of online resources that you can use.

[**News in Levels**](https://www.newsinlevels.com/) is a website with an [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.awesometap.ant) and a [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/NewsinLevels) that provides news stories in three levels. According to the sites home page,

> **Level 1** has the 1000 most important words. **Level 2** has the 2000 most important words, **Level 3** has the 3000 most important words.

(A related site is [Jokes in Levels](http://www.jokesinlevels.com/), which also has a [YouTube channnel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaJNTCkCbC7QlRPIan-QgNg), but the focus of these resources is listening practice, not reading.)

The website [**ESL Fast**](https://www.eslfast.com/) also has reading materials as various levels (six levels). The webpages also contain an audio version of the text (spoken in American English).

Answer (score 2):

Also:

- [Lit2Go](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/) - excellent resource of graded readers on various topics, all with audio.
- [aj3000 - Teaching English blog](http://aj3000.com/wp/free-graded-readers/) with new material regularly added
- [e-books](https://americanenglish.state.gov/ebooks) (with audio in US English) - provided  US Department of State as resource for teachers of English (thank you, US taxpayers)
- Voice of America has [Learn English](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/) section with articles in 3 levels, with audio.