# How to choose a foreign language to learn based on my interests?

Tags: self-learning, multiple-languages

I already know Russian and Ukrainian, I study English.
I'd like to find the next language to learn.
In fact, I'd like to know all the Romance languages, but I should start somewhere.
To begin with, I'm a programmer and study computer science at the university. I'd like to get a master's degree in another country.
In Germany and France, there is the possibility of receiving a free higher education, but neither French nor German do I like because of phonetics.
If I start learning German, it will be useful to me only in Germany. But if I start learning French, I can use it in France, the UK, Canada and other countries.
Moreover, if I know French, it can help me immigrate to Canada, although Canada is not the first in the list of countries for my immigration.
I'd like to learn Spanish, because in Spain there are funny girls!
Speaking of my interests, this is programming, music (pop, pop rock, folk, country (bluegrass), blues, jazz, classical music).
I also really like reading books. Fantasy and detective stories.
Which way will be right if I want to master several languages?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You got a downvote (not by me) because some of our members are much stricter about on and off-topic question. This is quite off-topic, because it is a personal advice based on opinions unlikely relevant to someone else. But when you have more specific questions about learning, ask away! Reading is excellent way to learn languages, see [graded readers](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graded-readers)  for any language of your interest, like [English](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/graded-readers-for-english)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a pretty good grasp of your priorities. We, strangers on the internet, can not make your life decisions for you.

As a factual point, German is also useful in Austria and Switzerland, at least.

I recommend that you try the various languages a little bit (maybe study each a bit via Duolingo or a similar free platform) and then make a slightly more informed choice.

Note that French and Spanish are both Romance languages, so they will support each other more than German will either. Learning both at the same time might also lead to minor setbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think not only interest but also the ultimate goal.

Funny girls speaking Spanish are also all over Latin America :-)

For immigration, higher level of English alone is preferable to "some" English and French, including Canada.

Just FYI, immigration to USA is quite unpredictable process. In Canada or Australia/NZ, you first immigrate, then look for a job. In USA, you try to win a H1B lottery to get a job permit, they you pay lawyers some more to get your permanent residency, and many years later, you might get permanent residency, if your company did not went bankrupt in between (which almost happened to me). Or can try to win "Green Card lottery" - Diversity Visa Lottery.

Scandinavian countries (Denmark, Sweden) and Netherlands have liberal immigration policies and (I believe) in many companies you can go by in English (but you should still learn local language), and might have affordable education too. But that would be better answers on Expats SE.

So this is not a "language learning" question, but priorities/goals question, and **you** need to do much more research about your goals and priorities. "Wants" versus "needs" and all that.

Answer (score 0):

Wanting to make money is a terrible motivation for learning a language. The desire for a monogamous romantic relationship is a little better, as long as it is coupled with a genuine love for the language and culture themselves. For this purpose, you can do a lot worse than move to China, South Korea or Southeast Asia.

The best motivation is from a hobby other than making money or love.

You say you want to attend a foreign university. There are famous ones throughout Europe that trace their origins to Medieval times, so Spanish, French, Italian or German will all do for this purpose, and you can rule out French and German because of your phonetic preferences.

If you like classical and rock music, you really should reconsider German. Portuguese has good jazz, and so does French (think Montreal Jazz Festival). If you like mystery novels, learning Norwegian or Swedish will help you read Stieg Larson and Jo Nesbø in the original. As for fantasy, again, GERMAN (i.e. Brothers Grimm, Richard Wagner), or maybe Finnish from which Tolkien derived his Elvish tongues.